# How to check non index directory using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect to the main domain if a directory(any) exists
 but does not have an index file(index.php/index.html), How to do that? I tried the below code but does not work.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.php  !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.html !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ / [L,R]
```

This will redirect a directory request to `/` if the `/index` file doesn't exist in that folder.